# Access a variable inside an asynchron function

Tags: javascript, function

I do have an asynchron function. In this function I need to have the value of an variable, which is defined outside the function. How is it possible to access the variable inside the asynchron function. Thanks for your help.

```js
var valueTest = "Hello";

doUpdate(source)
.then(myValue => {
  // do something with MyValue is working
  // How can I use the valueTest variable at this position?
  // I need it in the function doUpdateTest
  doUpdateTest(valueTest, myValue);
})
```

Comment: I assume this is JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, this is JavaScript.

Comment: "How can I use the valueTest variable at this position?" Exactly  like you did.

Comment: As long as you use arrow functions for your callbacks, you can access the scope where the async function was called (just like you did in your example)